# Jira Plugin user specific settings

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I've just started writing my first JIRA plugin and I need to implement some user specific settings, like the ones returned by this:

```
select * from jiraschema.propertyentry where ENTITY_NAME = 'ApplicationUser'
```

For now I was able to save only global settings for the plugin using PluginSettingsFactory, but I need to have different settings for each user. Does anyone know how to implement such a thing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution for accessing ApplicationUser properties. Here is my method, maybe it helps someone:

```
    UserPropertyManager userPropertyManager = ComponentAccessor.getUserPropertyManager();
    String propValue = null;

    //get a user specific property
    propValue = userPropertyManager.getPropertySet(ComponentAccessor.getJiraAuthenticationContext().getUser()).getAsActualType("workflow-mode").toString();

    //set a new user specific prop
    ComponentAccessor.getUserPropertyManager().getPropertySet(ComponentAccessor.getJiraAuthenticationContext().getUser()).setString("my_new_prop_name", "my_new_prop_value");
```